# GraphQLUnion with GraphQLList

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

My resolver can either return a list of PostType's or an ErrorType. However, I seem to be unable to describe this scenario in GraphQL:

```
const PostGetAllResponseType: GraphQLUnionType = new GraphQLUnionType({
  name: 'PostGetAllResponse',
  types: [GraphQLList(PostType), ErrorType],
  resolveType(value) {
    if (_.isArray(value)) {
      return GraphQLList(PostType)
    }

    return ErrorType
  },
})
```

How can I define a GraphQLUnion where one type is a GraphQLList and the other type is not (a list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the members of a union must be object types and not wrapping types (list and non-null are both wrapping types).

Comment: That's a shame. You'd expect that a list would be a first class type...